# using git to update itself

Tags: git, ubuntu, updates

I see on the git download page http://git-scm.com/downloads [among many other tutorial pages] that you can update git via itself. currently my desktop has git 1.7.9.5 and the newest is 1.8.1.3

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and running these commands in the home dir [~/]

I ran the following commands and had the following output:

```
~$ git version
git version 1.7.9.5
~$ git clone https://github.com/git/git.git
Cloning into 'git'...
remote: Counting objects: 149633, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (49646/49646), done.
remote: Total 149633 (delta 109386), reused 136311 (delta 98050)
Receiving objects: 100% (149633/149633), 34.92 MiB | 864 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (109386/109386), done.
~$ git version
git version 1.7.9.5
```

the end result is that the git version is the same. the only difference is that there is now a folder named git in my home directory with what I can only assume are the files that make up the software. I am clearly missing a few steps, I have searched all over Google and YouTube to find walk-throughs or some sort of a further explanation other than 'you can get git via git, just type this command'.

I apologize if this question has been answered before. If anybody knows where I can find the missing steps, I would very much appreciate a link/explanation.

I also apologize that this seems like an agonizingly simple thing that I could not figure out on my own.

And lastly, I am immensely grateful to any and all who will help me find an answer!

EDIT 3.18.13:
So I ended up having to do this again when I got a new laptop this week; thanks to you guys, I was able to run `git --version` and get back `git version 1.8.2`

I followed the directions from the git book, thanks [iltempo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428260/iltempo):

Then, compile and install:

```
$ tar -zxf git-1.7.2.2.tar.gz
$ cd git-1.7.2.2
$ make prefix=/usr/local all
$ sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

except that I got a zip file from github, so I unzipped it instead. I didn't do any other steps...

This is/was my first time building something from source so I am not really sure what some of the terms mentioned below mean:

'ensure `/usr/local/bin` is prepended to your path' -[iltempo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428260/iltempo)

I see [how to add a directory to my path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path/60221#60221), but I do not understand the meaning of this or what is happening when I do this.

Comment: This tutorial should be helpful for you: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-from-Source

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I should add that I tried this method. I am on Ubuntu so I tried "$ sudo apt-get install git"

the output said that I already had the newest version. Which wasn't true. Of course I did and apt-get update before trying to install via apt-get.

EDIT: I'm sorry were you suggesting that I follow the directions on compiling and installing? If so I will try that and then post how it went.

Comment: If you build git from source as described (not using yum or apt-get) it should end up as `/usr/local/bin/git`. If you ensure `/usr/local/bin` is prepended to your path, you should get the new version when running `git`.

Comment: Apt is a package manager and installing git through it will choose the git version that your distribution tests. What you have attempted is called "building from source". You have the source, but you miss the build step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Updating git with git" means updating the git repo *sources* with a `git pull`, once you have cloned https://github.com/git/git.

You would still need to *build* git from said sources, and install it before seeing a difference in the `git --version` command.

See the "[`INSTALL`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL)" file:

```
$ make prefix=/usr/local all doc info ;# as yourself
# make prefix=/usr/local install install-doc install-html install-info ;# as root
```

Since you are installing that updated git in /usr/local/bin, make sure that path comes first in your own `$PATH` environment variable (that you can [set in your `.profile`](https://askubuntu.com/a/60221/5470))

---

The other way would be to use apt-install (see "[How to upgrade Git on Ubuntu Hardy?](https://superuser.com/questions/56134/how-to-upgrade-git-on-ubuntu-hardy)"), but when I [look for the package git-core](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=git-core&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), the [Precise package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/git-core) only goes up to git_1.7.9.5.
That is why building from sources can be an alternative to waiting for git-core to be updated.

Comment: -1: **Never** install directly into `/usr`, that's the package manager's domain. Either install into `/usr/local` or at least use something like [CheckInstall](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/147).

Comment: @MichaelWild sure. I have fixed the path.

Comment: And after that you still need to make sure /usr/local comes first in PATH.

Comment: @pmr ok, I have added that step in the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you guys mean by $path, is that the path of the directory I am in on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

`git` uses the standard GNU autotools setup, see the `INSTALL` file in the sources. Then you can do the standard `./configure; make; make install` dance.

For my personal use I set it up with `prefix=$HOME`, and have an `alias git=~/bin/git` in my `.bashrc`, so `PATH` is not a issue.

Comment: That is also a good option, if you are alone on this server and wish that only you benefit from this upgrade. That avoid any unintended side-effect from modifying a program in the system path (like my answer suggests). +1